# How to combine elements while iterating over a csv file in python?

Tags: python

I have a csv file with contents like below:

| id1 | id2 | element |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | cat |
| A | B | dog |
| A | B | jaguar |
| C | D | kangaroo |
| S | T | elefant |
| S | T | lion |
| S | T | fox |

then, need to iterate over this list and group together element column to something like this:

id1: A, id2: B, element: cat, dog, jaguar

id1: C, id2: D, element: kangaroo

id1: S, id2: T, element: elefant, lion, fox

What will be my best approach?

I've tried creating a dataclass but when was parsing the values from the list, was just creating plain records and cannot figure out how to combine those element values over iteration.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the code you have written so far?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use pandas to do this.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id1': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'S', 'S', 'S'],
                'id2': ['B', 'B', 'B', 'D', 'T', 'T', 'T'],
                'element': ['cat', 'dog', 'jaguar', 'kangaroo', 'elefant', 'lion', 'fox']})

df.groupby(['id1', 'id2'])['element'].unique()
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a good candidate for [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/index.html).

Anyways, a basic version in python would be to just split the data by the csv (comma) separator. But anything more advanced, you'd want to use the `csv` module or something else. Here's a working example:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d=defaultdict(set)

for line in open('test.txt'): # use a with statement in anything non-trivial
    # basic check: skip the header line or if the line is empty
    if not line.strip() or line.startswith('id1'): continue
    id1,id2,element=line.strip().split(',')
    # since aggregating on id1 (it seems?) use that as the key
    d[id1].add(element)

>>> d['A']
set(['jaguar', 'dog', 'cat'])
```